# Переслать сообщение telebot

Tags: python, telebot

мне нужна помощь. Не могу нигде это найти.

Нужно, чтобы бот с канала(он там уже администратор) пересылал любое сообщение определенному chat_id.
Нигде не могу найти ответ на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте метод `forward_message`.

***Пример:***

```py
from telebot import TeleBot


bot = TeleBot('[token]')  # Не забудьте подставить свой токен!
TO_CHAT_ID = ...          # Не забудьте подставить нужный id!


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def all_messages(message):
    bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Данный код будет пересылать каждое сообщение.

Comment: nomnoms12, Спасибо огромное!